# Openseadragon error message not able to hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery, openseadragon

how to hide Openseadragon error message i tried

```
 jQuery(".openseadragon-message").attr("style", "opacity: 0 !important");
jQuery(".openseadragon-message").attr("style", "display: none !important");
```

its not working as error message is coming in viewer i am not able to figure it out , it would be really helpful if some one will guide me .

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (without jQuery)...

```
    viewer.addHandler('open-failed', () => {
      let el = document.querySelector('.openseadragon-message');
      el.style = 'display:none;';
    });
```